# Ошибка в телеграмм боте: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Для работы с телеграмм ботом использую прокси сервер. Версия Python 3.7.4.

Подрубил:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip install pywin32
pip install telepot
```

Сам код:

```
import telepot

basic_auth = ('login', 'passwd')
SetProxy = telepot.api.set_proxy("http://104.9.116.75:8881", basic_auth)
bot = telepot.Bot('921777438:OAF39zJDCrf5fVViNNuYsmXXZ-En8WSr3p0')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(387033819, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

Выполнение следующего кода вызывает ошибку: `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`. В интернете конкретного решения так и не нашел. Кто-то советует переустановить Python и все модули. Но что я не делал ошибка так и осталась. В чем по Вашему мнению может быть проблема?

Comment: Не уверен но мне кажется вы смешали два модуля telepot и telebot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot('921777438:OAF39zJDCrf5fVViNNuYsmXXZ-En8WSr3p0')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.telebot_token)
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://login:pass@12.11.22.33:8000'}}
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
      bot.send_message(387033819, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

Вот такой код был бы используя модуль **telebot**

Comment: Спасибо. То что доктор прописал =)